# Is it possible to left-justify (rather than centre-justify) successive lines in a WinForms message box?

Tags: .net, winforms, messagebox

Hopefully the question says it all.  We have some longish messages, separated by `CrLf` characters, and the lines come out centre-justified.

Can the lines be left-justified?

I can create a form and show it modally if I have to, but it would be nice not to have to.

---

Edit...

Apologies, people.  My bad... my damn fool question.

Turns out that the message box shown everywhere in my application is a custom one, and it inherits from a form, not from MessageBox.

Worse still, it was built with a label on it to display the text of the message... and, you guessed it, its TextAlign property was set to MiddleCenter.

I shall now go and bang my head on a spike as penance for troubling you good people...

Comment: A picture would be nice here, too.

Comment: Penance accepted. I forgive you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message box is left-aligned for me:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MessageBox.Show("It was the best of times, it was the worst of times." & vbNewLine & "The end.")
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]